# Delete a lot of files from Google Disk using Python

Tags: python

So I've downloaded a huge dataset (6GB) for training models, and I want to decrease the number of photos in each folder by 9 times (train, test and validation folders include 2 folders: MSIMUT, MSS).
I tried this code:

```
files = os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Kaggle_Data/tcga_coad_msi_mss/train/MSIMUT')
for file in files[:53334]:   # error
  os.remove(file)
```

But it gives me an error:

**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**

I could download all of that and remove photos manually, but downloading folders from Google disk takes like eternity, so there's no way I could use this option...

Comment: Can you provide a source for your implicit claim that `os.chdir()` returns anything but `None`? In what context are you expecting to have this method return anything, much less an iterable?

Comment: `os.chdir` does not automatically mean you can read the contents. Use `os.walk` or `os.listdir`

Answer (score 0):

NelsonGon's comment is the correct answer.  You want to do something like

```
import os
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Kaggle_Data/tcga_coad_msi_mss/train/MSIMUT/'
for file in os.listdir(path)[:53334]:
    os.remove(path+file)
```